# Complex query suggestion for ERP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am newbie to SQL. Although, i can write basic joins but my manager has asked me to provide one report with following requirement.

He wants to find all the invoices where the same item is present but with different packing..

From table structure standpoint:

```
TBL_ITEM (Table)
ITEM_ID (PK)
ITEM_NAME

TBL_PACKING (Table)
PACKING_ID (PK)
PACKING

TBL_INVOICE(Table)
INVOICE_ID (PK)
ITEM_ID (FK)
PACKING_ID (FK)
```

PS: I have eliminated columns which are not required for this..

Now based  on above table structure, here is the scenario.

1) Buyer A has bought two different items but same packing in a single invoice - This should not be part of list since item is different

2) Buyer B has bought one item twice with same packing in single invoice - NEED this LIST

3) Buyer C has bought one item with two different packing  - NEED this LIST

Please consider that all the scenario is applicable for an invoice so grouping should be first at invoice level then at item level...To ellaborate:

Buyer D bought items thrice in three different invoice

```
Invoice 1: Item A; packing 1kg
Invoice 2: Item B; packing 2kg
Invoice 3: Item A; packing 1kg; Item B; 2kg
```

for buyer D scenario, it should appear on the report since every invoice does not have combination of Item with same or different packing..

I have tried grouping and cursor but its not right way, i guess. want to know if this can be achieved with a query and if someone can help it would be great.

I am using MS SQL 2005

Comment: Hello,This is not home work. I work for a company who deals in ERP system. So recently the customer requested for a report which shows such detail since the rate calculation at packing level is not working as expected so the customer requested for a report to perform check and inform their parties accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple.  You can get the list of items doing:

```
select i.invoice_id, i.item_id
from tbl_invoice i
group by i.invoice_id, i.item_id
having min(i.packing_id) <> max(i.packing_id);
```

This gives you the list of invoice/item pairs that satisfy your question.